# Slow terminal print out

Tags: ssh, terminal, output

Just installed (netinstall) debian wheezy on a second machine newer machine however the terminal print out is noticeable slower than on the old machine although the new have faster CPU, RAM and HDD (an SSD). When login in on the new machine with ssh it is as fast as I expect it to be. It is obvious that the out put speed is related to computer/display and not just the computer.

For example the `dpkg -l` via virtual console takes 10s to print out and is instant via ssh.

X is not installed it is just a fresh installation of Debian Wheezy.

I assume this related to KMS but I am not sure where to start.

Comment: What video card do you have?

Comment: Its a Radeon HD 6310 integrated

Comment: Check processing doing disk io with iotop. Maybe there are processes running you don't know about. For example kde has some useless and annoying search program which runs frequently by default, and builds a cache you probably don't know about and will never use.

Comment: I have cheched for processes but this behavior is direct after netinstall i.e. their is more or less nothing runing in the background.

Comment: I solved the problem I missed to install firmware-linux-nonfree which enabled the DRM in KMS.

Comment: @RollerBoy, I suggest you post that as an answer as it may help other people having the same problem.